# Change image source from JavaScript in spring boot

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot

I am trying to change the source of an image in an html document every few seconds with a JavaScript function within a spring boot project but the typical way of changing the source does not appear to be working. I have tried to match the format of setting the image source with no luck either.
Here is where I initially set the source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<body>

<div style="text-align:center">
    <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button>
    <button onclick="zoomOut()">Zoom Out</button>
    <button onclick="zoomIn()">Zoom In</button>
    <br><br>
    <img id = "img1" src="../static/images/6car_1.png"; th:src="@{images/6car_1.png}"/>
</div>

    <script>
        var zoom = 6;
        var initialPath = "../static/images/";
        var count = 1;
        var isPlaying = true;
        playPhotos();
        function playPause() {
            if (isPlaying)
                isPlaying = false;
            else{
                isPlaying = true;
                playPhotos();
            }


        }
        function playPhotos(){
            var firstPart = initialPath  + zoom + "car_" + count +".png"
            var secondPart = "@{images/" + zoom + "car_" + count +".png}"
            if(count <=13){
                document.getElementById("img1").src = firstPart;
                th:src = secondPart;
                count++;
            }
            else{
                count = 1;
                document.getElementById("img1").src = firstPart;
                th:src = secondPart;
            }
            if(isPlaying){
                setTimeout("playPhotos()",200);
            }

        }

        function zoomOut(){
            if((zoom - 1) >= 1){
                zoom--;
            }
        }

        function zoomIn(){
            if((zoom + 1) <= 10){
                zoom++;
            }
        }
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is the playPhotos function bound and where is the isplaying variable? can you give me more details?

Comment: isPlaying is changed outside the function when a play/pause button is pressed. The playPhotos() method is at the root level of the script in the html document.

Comment: On the other hand, there is no need to replace `th:src` tag. This is tag is parsed by thymeleaf to insert (or replace) standard HTML `src` tag and never makes to the generated HTML output (you can see it for yourself in your browser's developer tools).

Comment: Be careful in spelling JavaScript. http://javascriptisnotjava.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var secondPart = "/images/"+zoom+"car_"+count+".png";
document.getElementById("img1").src = secondPart;
```

Comment: I said the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I edited it and it works because I created the variable "zoom" , "isPlaying" and called playPhotos (). You didn't specify those details ? If you have an error other than function operation, please upload all of your code as a snippet. I'll update my answer accordingly.

```js
var initialPath = "../static/images/";
var count = 1;
var isPlaying = true;
let zoom = "zoom"
playPhotos()

function playPhotos() {
  var firstPart = `${initialPath}${zoom}car_${count}.png`; //try
  var secondPart = `@{images/${zoom}car_${count}.png`;  // try
  if (count <= 13) {
    document.getElementById("img1").src = firstPart;
    th: src = secondPart;
    count++;
  } else {
    count = 1;
    document.getElementById("img1").src = firstPart;
    th: src = secondPart;
    count++;

  }
  if (isPlaying) {
    setTimeout("playPhotos()", 200);
  }
}
```

```html
<img id="img1" src="../static/images/6car_1.png" ; th:src="@{images/6car_1.png}" />
```

Comment: I am still having issues. Where the image should be just a image icon shows up. It appears to be blinking like it is trying to change the images but no image appears. The images exist because by commenting out the function the first image appears. The full code is above for context. I am not concerned about the zoom functions at the moment just trying to change the picture.

Comment: from what you said, You may have coded the file paths incorrectly. I suggest you check. You can share the template of the file structure.

Comment: @KyleS would you try typing file paths like this ? `var firstPart = `${initialPath}${zoom}car_${count}.png`;` 
`var secondPart = `@{images/${zoom}car_${count}.png`;`

Comment: the mistake must be here. Because your functions are working, but you can't see the pictures. I updated my answer. Can you try it again? @KyleS

Comment: also, if you leave a space between++, the path to the image will be blank. +path is not the same thing as + path.

Comment: Still doing the same thing. The file path looks identical to the initial path set in the html. Tell me if I am wrong though. Kind've odd.

Comment: I updated my codes. Have you tried changing the places I updated ?

Comment: Yes, no errors, just still the same result. I tried hard-coding the initial path that we know works from the initial src in the html with the same result. Maybe its not a file path issue?